# How to always serialize id rows in mysql when rows are deleted

Tags: php, mysql

When I delete rows in my database, the ID (auto_ increment) now longer to be in serial. Assuming I have `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and I delete rows `3 4 5`. After deletion I want ID to appear as `1 2 3 4 5 6` instead of `1 2 6 7 8 9`

Please how can I do this ?

**UPDATE**

I am using this code to display serial numbers to the comments generated from the db...(inside a while loop)

```
     <?php  
            $serial = 0; 
            $serial++; 
            echo"<div class='commentserial'>
                  <div id='$serial'></div> 
                    <a href='#$serial'>$serial</a> 
                  </diV>";
      ?>
```

Now that I have a pagination script on the comments display, when I click the second page instead of the serial numbering starts from 1 to $per_page Number.

So I felt if I use the database ID then the numbering wont start from 1 on subsequent paginated pages.

Comment: is the id primary key?

Comment: The Id of a record (the primary key) should be never changing. Why do you need that behavior?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do would not be good practice. Holes in primary keys are supposed not to be left there. Imagine for example having a reference in another table to ID `25` in your main table. If something changes in the main table, the reference would suddenly point to a different record.

The same goes for, say, web links. Having a URL like

```
details.html?id=255
```

suddenly point to a different record would be *very* bad.

If you want a perfectly serial ID, you'll probably be best off creating it on application level.

Comment: If you delete a record the reference should be made invalid (SET NULL) or the delete action should be cascaded (CASCADE) or the delect should be restricted right there (NO ACTION, RESTRICTED), but there should never be records pointing to no (longer) existing ones. Just set your contraints and this problem won't happen. But of course chaning primary keys is really a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

use: SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT offset, row_count

example:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])) $page=$_GET['page'];
else                     $page=1;

$row_count=10;     

$offset=($page-1)*$row_count;
$sql="select * from table1 limit $offset,$row_count";
```

Answer (score 0):

autoincrement is intended to be used only on synthetic keys. Those keys do not have any semantic meaning and therefore it doesn't matter whether they are in sequence or not.

If your ID column has a semantic meaning, you should give it a meaningful name and do not use autoincrement on it (you can consider creating a new synthetic key with autoincrement, if you need it).

To implement pagination you can use the database query for it. Consider the mysql keywords `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. This way your code generating the links does not have to concern about holes in your ID sequence.